# Is there a general consensus regarding which term is the multiplicand, and which is the multiplier in basic arithmetic multiplication?

Tags: terminology, definition, arithmetic, education, convention

**Is there a general consensus regarding which term is the multiplicand, and which is the multiplier in basic arithmetic multiplication?**

In my notes I stated that in the expression $a \times b$ the left hand term $a$ is the multiplicand.  I don't recall my original source.  When viewed in terms of naive usage and Western left to right reading order, the *multiplier* should be the left term.  That is, we read the expression as $a$ *times* $b$; meaning $b$ appears in the implied sum $a$ times.

A reference to an introductory math book predating Russell and Whitehead's Principia might be instructive.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why there is this distinction at all, when in the additive case both $a$ and $b$ are called addends or summands in $c = a +b$

Comment: Where $b$ is the multiplicand is also the convention given in the VNR Concise Encyclopedia of Mathematics by Gellert, et al. (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiplicand.html). The interpretation of $a \times b$ could be, e.g., "$a$ copies of $b$", or, "$b$ added together $a$ times", as you've stated. But because basic arithmetic multiplication is commutative, it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: [Transfinite ordinal multiplication forces the order of multiplicand and multiplier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143885/89922). But that's probably not "general" and "basic arithmetic multiplication".

Comment: Since $a + a$ is normally contracted to $2a = 2 \times a$ and not $a \times2$ (which is usually a contraction of $2 + 2 \dots a$ times), I feel the left operand is seen as multiplier.